# The “Filters -> Point Set-> Surface Reconstruction: Poisson”

Tags: meshlab

I installed MeshLab on Windows 10 and the poisson reconstruction is not available is the other reconstruction filters are present, also the compute normals is in the Point Set Filters.

Comment: Which version of Meshlab have you installed? I have v1.3.2_64bit on LUbuntu and the filter is there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Meshlab 64bit fp v2016.12 on Windows 10. You're correct that the poisson reconstruction is not in the "Filters->Point Set" menu. It is available in "Filters->Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction->Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction".